# Allowing a DLL located in Thunderbird profile in Software Restriction Policy

Tags: windows, security, group-policy

I'm implementing Software Restriction Policy on our workstations. The policy is to block everything except a list of white listed paths.

I'm trying to white list a directory inside Thunderbird user's profile to allow Lightning extension to work. The path is `%APPDATA%\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\*\extensions\{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}\components\calbasecomps.dll`.

The user's profile name is randomly generated, so I need a wildcard.

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work because of the wildcard. The DLL continues to be blocked by SRP.

I also tried to white list the certificate (the DLL is signed by Mozilla certificate), but this doesn't work. Maybe this apply only to signed .exe?

I white listed the hash for the moment, but this will require maintenance after each release of Thunderbird, so I would prefer to white list the path instead.

Applocker is not an option, we are using Windows 10 Pro.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem few minutes ago, and now I think the solution is simpler than you think.

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\*\extensions\{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}\components\calbasecomps.dll
```

become:

```
%APPDATA%\Thunderbird\Profiles\*\extensions\{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}\components\calbasecomps.dll
```

(without expliciting the "Roaming" subfolder, since APPDATA already resolves it.)

Anyway, IMHO, this expose to a targeted attack, since that DLL will remain user-writable.

Suggestions are welcome. ;-)

Comment: Arg! Thanks for the tip :). You are right about the hole this make. I would like to avoid, but this seem impossible. Too many badly coded apps put their exe/dll inside %APPDATA% (almost all web conference apps does that), this make many well known holes that can be abused.

Answer (score 1):

1. file a bug report with Mozilla!
2. NEVER define path rules with components like "%APPDATA%" which are under full control of the user (here both the variable and the directory are).
3. NEVER define registry path rules with such components too.
4. define a hash or a certificate rule for the DLL!